# Парсинг различных форматов Date

Tags: java, дата, datetime, locale, simpledateformat

Долго пытался разобраться как парсить различные форматы дат. 
На входе такие строки:

```
1987-03-23
null
1985-11-29
23-07-2000
17-10-1984
```

Нужно перевести в русский формат `dd.MM.yyyy`, а там где не соответствует паттерну вывести прочерк.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил вот так.

```
public class DateUtil {
public static Object extractTimestampInput(String strDate) {
    final List<String> dateFormats = Arrays.asList("yyyy-MM-dd", "dd-MM-yyyy", "MM-dd-yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf;
    //Наш формат 
    final String RU_FORMAT = "dd.MM.yyyy";
    String output = "-";
    //Пробегаем по всем паттернам
    for (String format : dateFormats) {
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, new Locale("ru"));
        //не пытаться анализировать даты, которые не совпадают с форматом
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        try {
            if (sdf.parse(strDate) != null) {
                Date date = sdf.parse(strDate);
                sdf.applyPattern(RU_FORMAT);
                return sdf.format(date);
            }
            break;
        } catch (ParseException e) {

        }
    }
    //Вывожу строку с прочерком
    return output;
  }
}
```

Вызвать метод из других классов можно так:

```
DateUtil.extractTimestampInput(входная_строка);
```

Comment: Класс у вас получился совсем не Util, а именно: 1. Возвращаемое значение всегда String, а не Object, что может сбивать. 2. В названии метода нигде не написано, что происходит преобразование из одного формата в другой. 3. Возвращаемое значение "-" не интуитивно, лучше бросать Exception. 4. Метод заточен под определенные фоматы, лучше передавать в него список необходимых форматов. А для себя сделать обертку с часто используемыми.

Comment: @ezhov_da, Спасибо за ответ! Прочерк - это требование задания, но, конечно, можно сделать правильнее. Название метода нужно изменить, хорошо. Сейчас подумаю насчёт Object, спасибо